# How to solve Error inflating class in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view that extends the constraint layout as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMyTitle"
        style="@style/LabelLowLevel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEditMy"
        style="@style/InlineButtonTransparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMyTitle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlayMy"
        style="@style/InlineButtonHot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonEditMy"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMyTitle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The view has some attributes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyCard">
        <attr name="Mytitle" format="string"/>
        <attr name="Mydescription" format="string"/>
        <attr name="Myid" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And then the corresponding Java class :

```
public class MyCard extends ConstraintLayout {
    public MyCard(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCard(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCard(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCard(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public String Description;
    public String Topic;
    public String MyId;

    private void init(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray CustomAttr = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCard);

        Description = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Mydescription);
        Topic = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Mytitle);
        MyId = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Myid);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.Mycard, this, true); // <<<<<< the error is raised here
        
        CustomAttr.recycle();           

    }
}
```

When running the code, I'm getting the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.colman.myapp/com.colman.myapp.Activity20_PersonalSpace}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49 in com.colman.myapp:layout/activity_activity20_personal_space: 
Binary XML file line #49 in com.colman.myapp:layout/activity_activity20_personal_space: 
Error inflating class com.colman.myapp.Libraries.views.MyCard
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the way you inflate the layout:

```
private void init(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    inflate(ctx, R.layout.Mycard, this);

    TypedArray CustomAttr = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCard);

    Description = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Mydescription);
    Topic = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Mytitle);
    MyId = CustomAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCard_Myid);

    CustomAttr.recycle();           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this way of inflating the layout. It's not working unfortunately.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton Ok, just for completeness: try to remove all constructors except `public MyCard(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)`

Answer (score -1):

try to change

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.Mycard, this, true);`

to

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.Mycard, this, false);`

Comment: It's just a typo. I replaced the real class name with MyCard for confidentiality reasons. This has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton okay. I edit my answer. try it out

Comment: tried that but it's not successful. Thanks though.